# Xerox Documate 3220 scanning slowly

Tags: performance, scanner

I have a Xerox Documate 3220 that takes about ten seconds to scan one page using the auto document feeder. I've tried reinstalling the driver, cleaning the scan glass, switching from TWAIN to WIA, and adjusting the scan resolution, but nothing seems to help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your expectations may be too high - 10 seconds per page is not unreasonable for a decent quality color scan.

What scan resolution and color depth do you have set ?

According to the [specs](https://buy.xerox.com/waroot/repository/documents/Xerox%20DocuMate%203220%20Datasheet.pdf), it should take 5 seconds to scan a color page at 200dpi - so if you are scanning a color page with a resolution of 300 dpi I would expect it to take about that long.

What happens if you scan  a black and white page at 200dpi ?  (This should, according to the specs, take about 2.6 seconds)

Comment: I'll have to test that and get back to you. I know that it used to scan much faster, but I don't remember if it was scanning in color or black and white previously.